# Custom Search Form in Joomla 3.3 using PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am new to Joomla and have managed to cope very well so far. But now I have been having difficulties creating my own Search form for products that I have created tables for in my database.

Here is what I want to do:

- Create tables in my Database (Done)
- Import CSV files in the tables (Done)
- Create a custom "Search form" on my Joomla page (Done)
- Write a php code to make use of the database and insert it on my Joomla directory
- Display the results on page...

May you please help me, any web-resources will be welcome...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display your data you have to create a new MVC component. [This official joomla tutorial would help you](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction).

For database tasks you have to get familiar with joomla database functions. [You could check this tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. I have been stuck for more than two weeks looking all over for a tutorial. I have checked both tutorials and I think it is better for me to get used to Joomla Joomla Database Functions.